# How to evaluate the security of transposition ciphers?

Tags: transposition-cipher, function-evaluation

how to evaluate the security of transposition ciphers? I am specifically interested in the security of turning grilles and how to (mathematically) evaluate their security.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: This is rather a broad question that talks about an unknown number of [transposition ciphers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_cipher). Could you try to be more specific in your question about where you fail in the (in)security evaluation?

Comment: I am especially interested in the so called "turning grille" and how to evaluate the security of this system in dependence of the size of the grille. I hope my question is clear now.

Comment: I now found a method to calculate the variation of grilles: If you have a grille with 6x6, then the number of variations $$n = 4^9 = 262144$$ Assuming uniform distribution across all four quadrants there are only $$n = 4 * \binom{9}{3}  * \binom{6}{2}  * \binom{4}{2}  * \binom{2}{2} = 30240 $$ But

Comment: But... what does that mean for security?

Comment: Well, as frequency analysis immediately leaks information about the plaintext, I guess the formal amount of security is, uh, none. I guess you are talking about fully reversing the cipher. Classical ciphers do not fare well against modern notions of security. You can quickly see that particular plaintext messages are *not* possible for a specific ciphertext after all. The modern notion is that the probability of every message *of the same size* is equally likely.

Comment: Let's take the above example: If there are 30240 possibilities, and an attacker tries to break the code with a brute-force-attack (because he doesn't know about frequency analysis), what's the expected value after how many times he will break it? Isn't it just $30240/2$?